# undefined is not an object(inspecting voximplantModule) voximplant connection

Tags: react-native, voximplant

The error at runtime shows in `index.android.js` in `node-modules>react-native-voximplant`. The file which is shown on there device on the red screen is `index.android.js` (the main file, the entry point)

```
this.connect = function(){
    VoxImplantModule.connect();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `import` directive is missing:

```
import VoxImplant from 'react-native-voximplant';
```

Voximplant React Native SDK has a demo project available that you can check [here](https://github.com/voximplant/react-native-demo/blob/master/index.android.js).